# Is it possible to recover project from PhpStorm cache?

Tags: phpstorm

I've deleted a folder with a project bypassing Recycle Bin. I've tried to recover files via Recuva and EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard, but some of them now have bad encoding or read protection (especially `*.vue` files).

Can I somehow recover the project using PhpStorm from its Local History?

Comment: If project is still recognizable in IDE (so not whole folder is deleted -- at least `.idea` must have remained) then you may use Local History and try to recover some files.

Comment: @LazyOne ah, whole folder was deleted. Thanks for the response.